# How to push data to azure event-hub for a node js application?

Tags: node.js, azure-eventhub

Below is the server.js code. Does the below code push data into the azure event hub? How to cross check the pushed data?
The data contains data ={name:'name',dob:'01-12-2000}

```
    const { EventHubProducerClient } = 
    require("@azure/event-hubs");

    const connectionString = "EVENT HUBS 
    NAMESPACE CONNECTION STRING";
    const eventHubName = "EVENT HUB NAME";
    
    async function main() {

    // Create a producer client to send messages to the event hub.
  const producer = new EventHubProducerClient(connectionString, eventHubName);

  // Prepare a batch of three events.
  const batch = await producer.createBatch();
  batch.tryAdd({ body: "First event" });
  batch.tryAdd({ body: "Second event" });
  batch.tryAdd({ body: "Third event" });    

  // Send the batch to the event hub.
  await producer.sendBatch(batch);

  // Close the producer client.
  await producer.close();

  console.log("A batch of three events have been sent to the event hub");
}

main().catch((err) => {
  console.log("Error occurred: ", err);
});
```

Comment: Please help.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the code sample that you've shared will publish events to Event Hubs.  That said, ignoring the return value of `batch.tryAdd` is a bad idea that may lead to data loss.  You may want to have a look at the [publishing sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/event-hubs/samples/v5/javascript/sendEvents.js) as an illustration of the recommended pattern.

By "cross-check", I assume that you'd like to read the events back and validate the payload; you would do this using the `EventHubConsumerClient` as demonstrated in the [receiving sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/event-hubs/samples/v5/javascript/receiveEvents.js).